How to debug without changing all the function signatures?
I'm learning Rust by reading the book and doing rustlings and watching videos; I think I understand what's happening here, but I don't understand what to do about it.
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Message {
    ChangeColor(u8, u8, u8),
    Echo(String),
    Move(Point),
    Quit,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}

struct State {
    color: (u8, u8, u8),
    position: Point,
    quit: bool,
    message: String,
}

impl State {
    fn change_color(&mut self, color: (u8, u8, u8)) {
        self.color = color;
    }

    fn quit(&mut self) {
        self.quit = true;
    }

    fn echo(&mut self, s: String) {
        self.message = s
    }

    fn move_position(&mut self, p: Point) {
        self.position = p;
    }

    fn process(&mut self, message: Message) {
        println!("{:#?}", &message);
        match message {
            Message::ChangeColor(r, g, b) => self.change_color((r, g, b)),
            Message::Echo(s) => self.echo(s),
            Message::Move(p) => self.move_position(p),
            Message::Quit => self.quit(),
        }

        println!("{:#?}", &message); // <--------
    }
} 

I understand the value of message is being moved on the last line.
I appreciate the memory safety of the borrow checker.
But I'm just trying to print message to see what happens to it. I know it's being partially moved and I want to witness what it looks like before and after the move.
Without changing the function signatures of everything, how can i just get a look at it?
And also, is the correct thing to do if I wanted to do something else with message just clone it or set it as mutable somehow?

The thing that changes is State not Message. So may be you wanted to debug  State instead? If you wanted to check message, you can add Clone to the derive and then use message.clone()  in the match condition.

state definitely changes, but message gets moved. The thing I'm getting confused by is what to do with something after it's been moved. And really if there's just a better way in general to debug or look at values because sometimes printlns dont even print to terminal for some reason

message is moved in the match expression, not in the last line. You are trying to print message after consuming it. At that point, it's gone. It might be partly deallocated. You just can't print it after it's gone, and I don't understand why you would want to.

After something has been moved, you cannot do anything anywhere other than the moved scope. If you want to debug, you can use dbg! macro. If the thing you want to  debug is the state, then I can provide an answer.

I want to witness what it looks like before and after the move - this is like saying "I want to witness what my object looks like before and after the free()". That's not how memory management works - after the free (in this case partial, but that's beside the point) the object is no longer usable. Also, you're not even changing the object, so even if you could somehow printing it after the move, you'd just get the same thing. If you want the value to remain usable, change match message to match &message and modify the match arms accordingly.

If you access a moved-from value, you must necessarily do so in an unsafe way (see for example std::mem::transmute which would let you create a reference outliving the moved-from value). If you do this, your program will potentially segfault. But likely that in this case, the value will not be any different at the 2nd point because moving from a value is a compile time concept - at runtime the value is just dropped at the end of its scope like usual which here is the end of the function scope.

@user2407038 But the compiler may use the liveness (aka. moving) information to make variables overlapping (potentially).

@ChayimFriedman Indeed, the compiler has a lot of freedom with when and how it drops. It is unspecified, since there is no standard to specify it, and could even different on different compiler versions. But this is exactly what the OP hopes to observe - "I want to witness what it looks like before and after the move". Here "it" being the memory location previously occupied by message.

@user4815162342 this is the right answer (the match &message) if you want to get it marked as the answer, make one and ill mark it as solved

@AndrewLuhring Done. Glad your issue got resolved!


I want to witness what it looks like before and after the move

This is not possible in safe Rust, and for good reason. It's like saying "I want to witness what my object looks like before and after destructing it" in C++. After a move (in this case partial, but that's beside the point) the value is no longer usable, and attempts to observe it, which would require unsafe code, would be undefined behavior, i.e. cause crashes or miscompilation.
If your actual goal is to observe the object after the match e.g. for logging purposes, you can modify your match not to move from the value. The simplest way to do that is to change match message to match &message and modify the match arms accordingly.

So there are a couple of things here.
First of all, the signatures should probably be updated a little anyway, the echo function can take impl Into<String> and then call .into() which means we don't have the partial move:
fn echo(&mut self, s: impl Into<String>) {
    self.message = s.into()
}

Message::Echo(ref s) => self.echo(s),

Although this does just clone the value, so the other options is leaving the parameter as String and just cloning s:
Message::Echo(ref s) => self.echo(s.clone()),

Simply calling .clone() might be the best option if you only want some debug code right now. Since you can easily remove it after, and then you don't have redundant cloning.
As for Point, you can derive Clone, Copy, since u8 implements Copy. This means you don't need to move the Point struct:
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}

Message::Move(p) => self.move_position(p),

